# Proxy caching to make cheap wimax useful

Tags: caching, proxy

Through my job, I can get cheap wimax but there’d be a bandwidth limit of 200MB/month

I often work on personal programming projects on the train to work. For this, I generally don’t need web access and even when I do need access; it’s usually for pages I’ve already visited.

Is there a way to cache my web visits in a way that’s relatively transparent. I’m thinking a caching proxy.

I want to be able to tell it:

- Cache everything from https://developer.mozilla.org (would be nice if they provided downloadable docs)
- Don’t cache google
- Cache javascript, css, and images from gmail and facebook (perhaps updating once a week)
- Block youtube altogether (bandwidth hog)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Does Squid Cache fit your bill?

http://www.squid-cache.org/